# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value error when appending to string in for loop

Tags: swift

I have setup a mutable array by using the `var` keyword. However, when attempting to use a `for` loop and modify each string within the array, I get a compile error stating that I cannot use mutating member on immutable value. It seemed logical that I could modify my array elements, because I used the `var` keyword. How did this become immutable? Also, I'm learning about data structures. So, can I extend the iterator protocol and make the `for` loop mutable?

```
var temples = ["blue", "red", "green", "red"]

for index in temples {
    //print(element.uppercased())
    //print(element)
    index.append(" triangles")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `index` is a `let` value inside the for loop , you can't use `.append` with it , instead you need

```
for (ind,value) in temples.enumerated()  {
  temples[ind] = "\(value) triangles" // +=
}
```

Comment: And "index" isn't an index :)

Comment: @DavidBerry an is hidden from vampires =D

Answer (score 1):

Your items are immutable because `String` is a `struct` and not an object, and a `for-in` loop treats the value as a `let`.  This would have worked if you had used `NSMutableString` which is a mutable object (instance of a `class`):

```
var temples: [NSMutableString] = ["blue", "red", "green", "red"]

for str in temples {
    str.append(" triangles")
}

print(temples)
```

> ```
> [blue triangles, red triangles, green triangles, red triangles]
> ```

but that isn't pure Swift.

---

Even if you made the values mutable by adding `var` to the `for` loop:

```
var temples = ["blue", "red", "green", "red"]

for var str in temples {
    str.append(" triangles")
    print(str)
}

print(temples)
```

> ```
> blue triangles
> red triangles
> green triangles
> red triangles
> ["blue", "red", "green", "red"]
> ```

It doesn't work, because `str` is a copy of the item in the array, not a reference to the object in the array because `String` is a `struct`, so modifying `str` doesn't change the array values.

---

> So, how do you do this in Swift?

Here are 3 ways:

**1. Loop over array indices and modify items in place:**

Loop over the `indices` of the array and use that index to modify the items directly in the array:

```
var temples = ["blue", "red", "green", "red"]

for index in temples.indices {
    temples[index].append(" triangles") // or temples[index] += " triangles"
}

print(temples)
```

> ```
> ["blue triangles", "red triangles", "green triangles", "red triangles"]
> ```

**2. Use `forEach` instead of a `for` loop:**

This could also be done using `forEach`:

```
temples.indices.forEach { temples[$0].append(" triangles") }
```

**3. Use a functional approach with `map`:**

A functional way would be to use `map` with concatenation:

```
temples = temples.map { $0 + " triangles" }
```

or `String` interpolation:

```
temples = temples.map { "\($0) triangles" }
```

---

@Sh_Khan in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52012868/1630618) shows a way to use `enumerated` and *String interpolation* to create new `String`s to replace the ones in the array instead of mutating the values in the array.